# Command Prompt_ Batch Rename inside Folders

Tags: command-prompt

Hello Fellow Strugglers of the World.

I am trying to rename the insides of several folders into the same structure of name (10.jpg, 20.jpg etc)
Is there a command prompt that helps you do that?
Pleeease help i am doing manually something that taaakes so long and it's driving me mad :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in an alternative way.

Try creating a txt file with all the filenames in the folder using the command **DIR /b > xxx.txt**

Load this txt, for example, in column A of a spreadsheet and create a formula to generate a **"RENAME " & cell(...,A) & " newname"**

Then export this text referring to the new column to a .BAT file to be executed in the folder.